# Queue3 Chapter 19 in Programming in Scala 2nd edition Question

Tags: scala

I'm doing a code review for the Queue3 example in the Programming in Scala 2nd edition by Odersky et al. And I guess i'm stuck.

Here's the code:
http://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_2ed/examples/type-parameterization/Queues3.scala

```
object Queues3 {
  class Queue[T](
    private val leading: List[T], 
    private val trailing: List[T] 
  ) {
    private def mirror = 
      if (leading.isEmpty)
        new Queue(trailing.reverse, Nil)
      else
        this

    def head = mirror.leading.head

    def tail = { 
      val q = mirror 
      new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing) 
    }

    def enqueue(x: T) = 
      new Queue(leading, x :: trailing)
    override def toString = 
      leading ::: trailing.reverse mkString ("Queue(", ", ", ")")
  }

  object Queue {
    // constructs a queue with initial elements `xs'
    def apply[T](xs: T*) = new Queue[T](xs.toList, Nil)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val q = Queue[Int]() enqueue 1 enqueue 2
    println(q)
  }
}
```

So it's trying to implement a queue in a functional programming way with speed similar to the imperative way.

So to do this it'll split the queue into two part so we can append toward the end by constant speed. The whole queue is basically:

```
leading ::: trailing.reverse
```

The book is saying that worst case scenario is when the leading is empty.

So if code do this

```
val q = Queue[Int]() enqueue 1 enqueue 2
```

Then,
q.leading is List() and q.trailing is List(2,1)

So when I call q.head, the book stated that since leading is empty, mirror will copy everything from trailing, reverse it and set it as leading.

The problem is I don't think this work because it's a method? So it doesn't persist via state. Because I made the code properties public and checked q.leading and q.trailing and the value is the same. What I'm expecting after I do q.head is:

```
q.leading is List(1,2) and q.trailing is List()
```

But it is not, am I missing something? Is this some FP paradigm that I'm missing? Because I think it can work the way I think it should work if head and tail methods is change to var.

Thank you for your time.

Edit making the properties public:

<strike>private</strike> val leading: List[T], 
<strike>private</strike> val trailing: List[T]

edit:
chapter 19 in 1st edition:
http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is that `head` and `tail` methods doesn't return new `Queue`. And you are inspecting the old one. Checkout this versions of `head` and `tail`. Now they return new `Queue` in a tuple.

```
def head: (T, Queue[T]) = {
    val q = mirror
    (q.leading.head, q)
  }

def tail: (Queue[T], Queue[T]) = {
  val q = mirror
  (new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing), q)
}
```

As you can see, `mirror` works fine.

```
val q = Queue[Int]() enqueue 1 enqueue 2
println(q)
printLT(q)
val q1 = q.head
println(q1._1)
printLT(q1._2)

def printLT[A](q: Queue[A]) {
  println("leading: " + q.leading)
  println("trailing: " + q.trailing)
}
```

Output:

```
Queue(1, 2)
leading: List()
trailing: List(2, 1)
1
leading: List(1, 2)
trailing: List()
```

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Because it returns a new instance of List I need to set it to a new val. And because head and tail method only return  to see just more than an int, you created a tuple so I can see the head value and the leading. So it seems like tail is popping. Nevertheless this example helped me greatly. Thank you.